# What is the best way to write to a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I would like to write some data to a file in Ruby. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
File.open("a_file", "w") do |f|
    f.write "some data"
end
```

You can also use `f << "some data"` or `f.puts "some data"` according to personal taste/necessity to have newlines. Change the `"w"` to `"a"` if you want to append to the file instead of truncating with each open.

Comment: I concur with passing a block to File.open. This is the safest method as whatever happens in there (correct execution, exception, etc), the file is guaranteed to be closed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'rio'
rio('foo.txt') < 'bar'
```

http://rio.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 2):

Beyond [File.new](http://www.meshplex.org/wiki/Ruby/File_handling_Input_Output) or [File.open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) (and all the other fun IO stuff) you may wish, particularly if you're saving from and loading back into Ruby and your data is in objects, to look at using [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) to save and load your objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using File::open is the best way to go:

```
File.open("/path/to/file", "w") do |file|
  file.puts "Hello file!"
end
```

As previously stated, you can use "a" instead of "w" to append to the file. May other modes are available, listed under `ri IO`, or at the [Ruby Quickref](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html).

Answer (score -2):

```
filey = File.new("/path/to/the/file", APPEND)
filey.puts "stuff to write"
```